# Drop user in MySQL with malformed host (%;)

Tags: mysql

I've made a mistake when granting privileges to an user in a MySQL box,

```
grant USAGE ON *.* to 'mylovelyuser'@'%;';
```

As you can see, I've written the host like %; so now I'm trying to find the way to drop it

a `drop user 'mylovelyuser'@'%;';` didn't work :(

Thanks!
EDIT, doing a `select user,host from mysql.user;` looks like this:

```
+------------------+-------------+
| user             | host        |
+------------------+-------------+

| mylovelyuser       | %;
         |
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for me

```
 DROP USER 'mylovelyuser'@'%;'; 
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then

```
SELECT `Host`, `User` FROM `mysql`.`user`;
```

no longer shows the user

Comment: Uhm, I think I have another problem. I just edited my original post with the output of the user list. thanks!